# Trouble booting: ACPI PCC probe failed

Tags: boot

I was just doing my thing on Ubuntu 15.04 and then I couldn't launch Minecraft no matter how I tried so I rebooted and the screen went like this:

```
[0.036510] Ignoring BGRT: Invalid status (expected1)
[6.960782] ACPI PCC probe failed
starting version 219
```

It went into command line and completely black. With this on my screen it looked a bit like terminal now that I think about it.

So I was pretty scared but I rebooted in recovery and repaired broken packages booted up my laptop and now everything is slow and I can't run steam and youtube videos are slow and clunky. Any suggestions or solutions?